# Java Concurrency: Can I create a pool using worker thread

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm new to `java.uti.concurrent` package. I'm trying to develop a socket listner class by using `ExecutorService`. Here is my Main code snippet:

```
    while (!getExit()) {

        try{
            logger.info("RequestListner.run(): listening for new request...");
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            logger.info("RequestListner.run(): got new request");
            MyTask task = new MyTask(socket);
            pool.submit(task);
            logger.info("RequestListner.run(): submitted new request to pool");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("RequestListner.run(): Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My `MyTask` class have a `ExecutorService` object, it will submit `MyTask2` tasks. (my intension is to exeute multi thread processing for my each socket connection)

My application is accepting my socket client request and creating pool of `MyTask2`, executing fine. But is accepting my second socket client connection only after finishing my frist request.

Can anybody please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

-Venkat Papana

Comment: Are you doing anything in the `MyTask` constructor that would block?

Comment: Thank you @SimonJ, I found the issue. In my MyTask constructor I'm calling run() method that internally calling Future's get() method.
Thank you very much SimonJ.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of `Executor` or `ExecutorService` have you created ?

```
public static final POOL_SIZE = 5;
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
```

Comment: Hi Ammar, Yes i'm, createing the Executors.newFixedThreadPool only
`pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOLSIZE);`
in my `Main` program as weel as in my `MyTask` prog.

Answer (score 0):

You need not create a "pool" of ExecutorService, just use one ExecutorService and it itself manages a pool of threads internally.

And also your implementation of ExecutorService should be able to execute given number of tasks paralelly. For e.g., use [Executors.new*ThreadPool()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) methods in it and parameterize it accordingly.

Comment: Hi Suraj, I'm actually creating only one ExecutorService object only. 
`ExecutorService pool;`

Comment: ok cool..i see you have edited your question...can u tell me how you create your executor service

Comment: I'm using `pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOLSIZE);` in my `Main` and `MyTask` programs.